# Capture the source of an event in GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How does one capture the cause of the event in GA. For example-

Say in my eCommerce application, I have to get the count of people who have bought a particular product because of the Ad they saw about it. Now the ad could have been shown a couple of days back also.

GA knows about who is clicking on ads and also who is purchasing the product since I am pushing 2 individual events (`ad_click` and `product_purchased`) respectively. But there is no way to figure out how many of them bought the product because of the ad.

Comment: So you are talking about an ad on your own platform, is that correct? You do not refer to ad of advertising on Google or 3rd party sites, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. There is an ad on my own platform which links to the profile page of that product, again on my own platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to analyze aggregated data, then you can use GA's Events Flow report, which shows the journey of the user through events. It will show you how many events led to the other event: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45QYuTmmd6Y

If you would like to see this information for each user specifically, and would like to send it to a CRM or something, then you will have to store this data in your own cookie. I suggest you take a look at this project that can help you to store campaign information and to retrieve it using JS: https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative